# How to get Twitter #hashtag id

Tags: javascript, twitter

How can I get `#<name>` id, for example like this number `345170787868762112`. I got it from following example: http://codepen.io/jasonmayes/pen/Ioype .

Maybe it is not `#hashtag` id, but can anyone explain, what it is then and how could I find it for any kind of `#hashtag`?

Tried to google it, but didn't find any relevant result for that.

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the comments in the code you linked to?

```
/**
 * ### HOW TO CREATE A VALID ID TO USE: ###
 * Go to www.twitter.com and sign in as normal, go to your settings page.
 * Go to "Widgets" on the left hand side.
 * Create a new widget for what you need eg "user time line" or "search" etc.
 * Feel free to check "exclude replies" if you don't want replies in results.
 * Now go back to settings page, and then go back to widgets page and
 * you should see the widget you just created. Click edit.
 * Look at the URL in your web browser, you will see a long number like this:
 * 345735908357048478
 * Use this as your ID below instead!
 */
```

Those aren't the IDs of hashtags - they're widget IDs which you have previously configured to *search* for hashtags.